# What does pressing SHIFT+DEL in project tree in Visual Studio do?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, hotkeys

I pressed <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> on source code file name in project tree in Visual Studio
and it became grayed. What does it do? How can I undo?

Thanks

UPDATE: Refactored hot-key name in the title. My apologies to all the parties affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "cut". Generally, in Windows, it's the same as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
You can undo it by either ignoring it, or pasting it back.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INS</kbd> is the corresponding alternative to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Back in the DOS days, these were the shortcuts for copying, cutting, and pasting, I believe.

(And to be complete, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>INS</kbd> is copy)

Comment: Oh thanks! I wonder why they plugged in this Windows behaviour into project tree controls? But it might be useful when you want to move a file to another project.